# Django Taggit Module Installation Error: No module named setup tools

Tags: python, django

The title basically explains it all.

I am running Windows 8 (windows 7 was previously installed... If it helps with answering) and am using Python 2.7.

Upon using the code:

```
python setup.py install
```

I am getting this error:

C:\Users\Nicholas\Desktop\taggit>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 52, in 
    from setuptools import setup
ImportError: No module named setuptools

Any help?
Thanks in advance
Nicholas

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install `setuptools`, which allows packages to be configured for your Python installation. It is not included with the default Python installer.

From [this link](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools) you can download  Windows installers for many Python packages (I have linked it directly to setuptools). Make sure you download the version that matches your Python installation.

Comment: Thank you very much Burhan. You just saved me from a day's worth of frustration.

Answer (score 1):

in Python 3:

```
pip3 install setuptools
```

And in Python 2.x:

```
pip install setuptools
```

Comment: I am on a Windows platform, not a Linux distro at the moment.

Comment: If you don't have setuptools, chances are you also don't have pip.